# VSCode shows problems that don't affect to compilation

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

VSCode shows me a tons of problems with typescript but this problems don't affect on compilation. I can't understand why my colleagues don't see these issues like me. How can I remove this check?

[Problem output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCxDj.png)

Comment: nice to see "-" without any comments ))) LOL

Comment: without any code related to the code we can't help, focus on the first error in the file

Comment: I don't need to fix these issues. The major issue is that the same codebase show issues on my laptop and do not show any problems on the laptop of my colleagues. I have some check but couldn't understand how to switch off.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the typescript version. Vscode typescript version was higher than project's and in my case when I use vscode typescript's version I see type errors

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).